# How do you remove the parent name from the child name with grouped products in woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Grouped products appear like this Parent Product Name → Child Product Name
The title for the product name appears like this in the cart, checkout, and any messages on the product page and checkout. How do you remove the parent name with the arrow from a grouped product title? Not sure where to start on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is defined here https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-simple.php#L66

You can change it with woocommerce_product_title filter like this:

```
function gfl_product_title($title, $product) {
    return $product->post->post_title;;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_title', 'gfl_product_title', 10, 2);
```